# LibGDX - IllegalArgumentException causes my game to crash whenever my main character touches a Coin

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, 2d, collision

Trying to figure out why my Android game crashes whenever the player touches an animated coin. I have attached an image of the LogCat and my code is below (NOTE: all game objects in **![Renderer]** are in an arraylist called *toRender*. the **2** coins in the game are currently held in the **3rd and 4th position** in the list). **Renderer** and **Coin** classes respectively:

```
public class Renderer extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture background;
    private ArrayList<GameObject> toRender;
    private Timer timer;
    private float delta;
    private Game game;

    public Renderer(ArrayList<GameObject> toRender) {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background2.png"));
        this.toRender = toRender;
        timer = Timer.getInstance();
    }

    public void collect() {
        // for every object in toRender (an arraylist of objects)
        for (GameObject o : toRender) {
            // if player collides with/collects an object
            if (Player.getInstance(null).hasCollected(o)) {
                // if its the first coin that he collides with, dispose it
                if (o.equals((Coin) toRender.get(3))) {
                    ((Coin) toRender.get(3)).dispose();
                }
                // if its the second coin that he collides with, dispose it
                if (o.equals((Coin) toRender.get(4))) {
                    ((Coin) toRender.get(4)).dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void beginRendering() {
        delta = Timer.getInstance().getTime();
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        timer.drawTime(batch);
        for (GameObject object : toRender) {
            object.update();
            boolean objectIsntCoin = !(object.equals(toRender.get(3)) ||
                    object.equals(toRender.get(4))); //the 2 coins are in the 3rd and 4th position in the array list
            // draw every object's sprite apart from coin, since coin should render the animation rather than the sprite
            if (objectIsntCoin) {
                object.draw(batch);
            }
        }
        collect();

        ((Flag) toRender.get(toRender.size() - 1)).drawLevelComplete(batch);
        // if the coin exists (i.e. hasn't been disposed), render the animation
        if (((Coin) toRender.get(3)).checkExists()) {
            ((Coin) toRender.get(3)).render(delta);
        }
        // if the coin exists (i.e. hasn't been disposed), render the animation
        if (((Coin) toRender.get(4)).checkExists()) {
            ((Coin) toRender.get(4)).render(delta);
        }

        batch.end();
    }
}

public class Coin extends GameObject implements Screen {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Animation animation;
    private float time;
    private float xPos;
    private float yPos;
    private Rectangle objectRect;
    private boolean exists;

    public Coin(Sprite spr, float xPos, float yPos, float radius) {
        super(spr, xPos, yPos, radius);
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        objectRect = new Rectangle(getxPos(), getyPos(), getSprite().getWidth(), getSprite().getHeight());
        exists = true;
        time = 0;
        show();
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return objectRect;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(time += delta), xPos, yPos);
        batch.end();
    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        animation = new Animation(1 / 8f,
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin1.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin2.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin3.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin4.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin5.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin6.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin7.png"))),
                new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("coin8.png"))));
        animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        exists = false;
    }

    public boolean checkExists() {
        return exists;
    }
}
```

LogCat:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g74KB.png)

[image]

So the errors that the LogCat point to: 
1)**dispose() method in Coin:**
batch.dispose();

2)**collect() method in Renderer:**
if(o.equals((Coin) toRender.get(3))) {

3)**beginRendering() method in Renderer:**
for (GameObject object : toRender) {

Does anyone know why my program is crashing? I just want the animated coin to disappear when the **Player** touches it. Currently the coin DOES disappear, the application just shuts down immediately after though. Have been stuck on this for a while so any insight is **highly** appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to mention that downcasting the objects in `toRender` like you are is both dangerous and indicates there is a flaw in your design. Additionally, you'll notice that `equals(Object)` accepts an Object as an argument; you don't need to cast it to `Coin`.

Anyway, the reason your program is crashing is explained in the IllegalArgumentException message,

> buffer not allocated with newUnsafeByteBuffer or already disposed.

You're trying to dispose your `Coin`'s batch when it has *already* been disposed.

In your `collect()` method, you loop through the objects, and you dispose of their batches, but the `Coin` objects themselves are never removed from your `toRender` list. So, the next time `collect()` is called, it will loop through those same `Coin` objects and try to dispose of them again, and an exception is thrown.

The solution is to remove the `Coin` objects from your `toRender` list when they no longer belong in your game's scene. However, you can't remove an element from a list while you're iterating over it, as this would disrupt the loop. Instead, remove them like so:

```
public void collect() {
    // Holds the Coins we want to remove from toRender
    final Collection<GameObject> toRemove = new LinkedList<>();

    for (GameObject o : toRender) {
        if (Player.getInstance(null).hasCollected(o)) {
            if (o.equals(toRender.get(3))) {
                final Coin coin = (Coin) toRender.get(3);
                coin.dispose();
                toRemove.add(coin);
            }
            if (o.equals(toRender.get(4))) {
                final Coin coin = (Coin) toRender.get(4);
                coin.dispose();
                toRemove.add(coin);
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove the collected Coins
    toRender.removeAll(toRemove);
}
```

Comment: I added this in and made a few changes elsewhere in the code and now it works, thank you. I decided to add 2 methods setType(String type) and getType() to the GameObject abstract class and in each object constructor (e.g. coin) i'd write something like setType("coin") or setType("player"). The for loops were a lot smaller (and cleaner) in the end and I used one to fixed an error in the beginRendering method where the 3rd and 4th position of the list is always treated as a coin even after coins get removed. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @DeuceDeuce don't forget to click accept on the answer